# Why do you reject negative base solution for Logs?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$log_x64=2$ translates to $x^2=64$

This solves to $x=\pm8$

Why do you reject the solution of $x=-8$ ?
Doesn't it successfully check?

$log_{-8}64=2$ means "The exponent for -8 to get 64 is 2"
which is a true statement, no ?

Comment: because $\log_x (a)=\frac{\ell n(a)}{\ell n(x)}$ and $\ell n$ is define only for $x>0$.

Comment: -8 is also a solution, who rejects it?( unless complex numbers are not allowed.)

Comment: No consensus here.

Comment: Simply because $\log$ functions are not defined for negative bases

Comment: Why not?  Logs are just another way of writing exponent form.  And you can have negative bases in exponent form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\log_{-8}x$ would be an inverse function of $(-8)^x$ but this function does not behave well at all. What would be $(-8)^π$ for example?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-8%5Epi

Comment: @Arjang who knows how wolfram alpha is calculating that number? It could mean anything. Until they start publically disclosing wolfram alpha's definitions, algorithms, and internal workings, it will continue to have no bearing on these matters.

Comment: @goblin : any scientific calculator would give the same answer as well; no need for wolfram alpha source code

Comment: @Arjang, I think you'll find that most scientific calculators will throw an error. In any event, without an explicit definition, the number is meaningless.

Comment: Badly behaved is a lot different than not existing, right?

Comment: @JackOfAll Yes that's true.

Answer (score 0):

Because $\log$ is the inverse of $\exp$ with base $-8$. Think about the domain of the function $x\to(-8)^x$. Is it defined for $x=1/2$ or in general for fractions $m/(2n)$? So in my opinion negative bases are avoided to be able to define the exponential everywhere.

Comment: Why is $-8^x$ illegal?  Sure, it may not be a nice round number, but that's  a far cry from undefined like a div by 0.   Seems like a legitimate operation.

Comment: Sure, it may not be a nice convenient consistent function, but does that mean it's not allowed ?